# Ajax POST MyUrl 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

i'm working on some grails code and geting this error whenever the ajax function is getting the response from the controller action!

the Ajax function is passing the parameters and controller function is performed after the return i get this error from the browser developing tool.

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlMap.myUrl_url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        pId: pId,
        stId: stId
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $supplementaryHolder.html(data);
    }
})
```

Here is the controller function !

```
def deleteSupplementary = {

    if (!modifyService.deletePlacement(params.long('pId'))) {
      flash.error = g.message(code: 'student.delete.placement.failed')
    }
     return params.stId;

  }
```

Comment: Use console.log(urlMap.myUrl_url); before AJAX. URL is correct?

Comment: yes it is correct ! otherwise the controller function won't get the parameter and work fine !

Comment: Add your controller code as well.

Comment: Do you have the address somewhere on the internet, or locally?

Comment: I've added the controller function which returns a string and as debugged it, it's working well!

Comment: @JarosławOsmólski No it's locally! i have initialised the address variable. and in the Ajax function it's a reference to it

Comment: not unusual to have API send back error headers when data not available based on params sent so you can use them in front end code. Your overall issue is not very clear

Comment: What happens if you change return to render?

Comment: @LalitAgarwal thanks for the hint ! worked actually :) put it as an answer and i'll accept it !

Comment: @Mich Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake seems to be at this line

```
return params.stId;
```

change it to

```
render params.stId;
```